# How to insert the value according to the user condition on the same database field

Tags: codeigniter

I have two textbox credit and debit textbox.If the user enters the value in debit textbox then the value have to be stored on amount field and in dc field it have to store as d..when the user enters the value on credit textbox then the value have to store on amount field and in dc field it have to be stored as c..My doubt is possible to save the credit or debit value in same amount fields according to user condition

Comment: Your question might be clearer if you provide the code you have tried.

Comment: i just want to know..it's possible or not..i didn't get any idea to do this

Comment: So you want the "amount box" to display the (credit - debit) value that is read from the database from the credit and debit fields that are updated via the credit and debit text boxes?

Comment: Yes..I found the solution..Thanks..